# How to stop Chrome from causing Download folder to reappear in gallery?

Tags: downloading, gallery, chrome-for-android

Wanting to exclude the `Download` from being scanned by the **Gallery** application, I do as required, and create a:

```
.nomedia
```

file in the `Download` folder. That correctly causes the `Download` folder to vanish from **Gallery**. And all is well.

### But then

If I **Save** an image from Chrome, the `Download` folder reappears in **Gallery**. This coincides with Chrome adding a special file to the `Download` folder:

```
ic.bin
```

[image]

Deleting the `ic.bin` file does not cause the folder to disappear from Gallery. Deleting, and **re**-adding the `.nomedia` file to the `Download` folder **does** cause the `Download` folder to vanish from **Gallery**.

I could ask this a number of alternate ways:

- how do I ***really*** prevent a folder from being scanned by **Gallery**?
- how do I deny file creation permission of a file called `ic.bin` in the `Download` folder?
- how do I deny file creation permission of a file called `ic.bin` in *any* folder?
- how do I stop Chrome from creating an `ic.bin` file in the **Download** folder?
- how do I stop the `Download` folder from reappearing in **Gallery**?
- how do I prevent Chrome from causing the `Download` folder from reappearing in the **Gallery**?

What I'm really asking is, *"How do I exclude a folder from the **Gallery**?"*, given that `.nomedia` doesn't always work.

> Device: Nexus 4
>   Android version: 4.2.1

Comment: That really looks very strange. Not sure if it helps, but lacking other ideas: Remove both files, then create an empty `ic.bin` (making it read-only) plus the empty `.nomedia` (in this order). It's a wild guess, but maybe the contents of `ic.bin` are a key to it. Thus having created a read-only `ic.bin` should prevent Chrome from placing its own copy. No guarantees, as said -- just a wild guess, but worth a try.

Comment: Ian, it would be nice if you could let us know whether the hint solved your problem. If so, I'd convert it into an answer -- so other users with the same problem would know about the solution.

Comment: @Izzy Sorry for the delay; [my Nexus 4 broke](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34831/cant-swipe-down-notifications-on-nexus-4) and i'm using a spare. The problem is that there is no way to mark files as `Read only`; the MPC interface in Windows doesn't allow doing that. The other issue i discovered is that it's not just a problem with **Chrome**'s download folder. [Another app](http://tinyurl.com/bvpr38q), that saves images into its own private folder with a `.nomedia` file, also appear  in the Gallery once you save a file there.

Comment: As for marking r/o: You could use a file explorer on Android for that. Dunno about the other app you mention, sorry...

Comment: @Izzy The point was that `ic.bin` is a red herring. It seems that `.nomedia` is only honored if it is the **last** file written to the folder. **Edit**: which might provide a solution. If it ***is*** date based, then perhaps Android has a way to alter the date of a file to `December 25th, 3091`

Comment: Just another though, using atomics: you could use Tasker: If file_created(`ic.bin`) then delete(`ic.bin`, `.nomedia`) & create(`.nomedia`)...

Comment: I think it's so because Chrome is manually adding that file to the android media database (rather than the scanner is scanning the file). And the .nomedia-File is only been considered by the media scanner.

Answer (score 1):

I know this doesn't answer your exact question. You'll save yourself a lot of time and effort going with another picture app such as [QuickPic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alensw.PicFolder&hl=en)

It's fast and customizable, and you can select which folders to include OR exclude :)

Do yourself a favor and disable Gallery.

Comment: I do use QuickPic; for this exact reason. But it would still be nice to have a solution for everyone else (and me).