# Can't swipe down notifications on Nexus 4

Tags: notification-bar, nexus-4

i have a 12 day old Nexus 4 and i can't swipe down the notifications bar.

- i've tried turning it off
- i've tried performing a factory reset

If i go into an application that supports *landscape* mode (e.g. Chrome), and turn the phone landscape, then i ***can*** swipe down notifications from the *"top"*.

But then i can't click the "Home" button, which is then located on on the right hand side of the screen, which is the top of the physical phone - near the earpiece).

[image]

**Edit**: i forgot that the whole point of including the picture was to demonstrate the home button can't be clicked when it's near the "earphone" (e.g. on the right in the above photo). Unfortunately, in this picture all shadow detail as been lost. But trust me, the earphone is on the right side in the above photo.

- Nexus 4; Model LG-E960

### See also

- [Droid RAZR Support > Can't swipe down the notification bar](http://www.droidforums.net/forum/droid-razr-support/223785-cant-swipe-down-notification-bar.html)
- [Android Central - notification bar not opening](http://forums.androidcentral.com/htc-evo-4g-lte/178673-notification-bar-not-opening.html)

Comment: A hardware issue may be? Are you able to swipe / touch in that particular area when it's showing something else than notification bar?

Comment: @SurajBajaj No. In the above picture, where the *"top"* of the phone is now on the right, i **cannot** click on the `Home`, `Back`, or `Switch` buttons.

Comment: I would say it's probably a hardware issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a hardware issue most likely.

The only way to solve this would be to send the device back to the manufacturer.

Comment: Update: It was a hardware issue. It was returned and a replacement was shipped out.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with my nexus 4 and its definitely a hardware issue for sure...avoid factory reset and rebooting of your phone becoz it wont change anything..but on a temporary basis u can put the display setting of auto rotate on and when there is issue to swipe in portrait you can auto rotate your screen in landscape through an app swipe it and three four time down and then it would start working in portrait form also.